# include helper file in blade template page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering how do you include a helpers function for form validation. I'm new to laravel so I only have a basic understanding of how it works but I don't even know how to include file which has functions in it that I want to use to validate a form for error checking. This is what I want to use in all my forms. How do I have this page on a global scale on pages that have forms

helper.php

```
<?php 
    public function hasError($error) {
    if(strlen($error) > 0) {
        echo "has-error";
    }
}
```

and insdie this page i use hasError 
create.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group <?php hasError($errors->get("keywords")) ?>">
    {{ Form::label('keywords', 'Keywords', array('class' => 'col-sm-2  control-label')) }}
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ Form::text('keywords', NULL, array(
                    'placeHolder' => 'Keywords',
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you handle validation in your controller? When you return like this after validation:

```
        // Return error
        return Redirect::back()
                        ->withInput()
                        ->withErrors($validator);
```

You can show errors like this:

```
<small class="red">{{{ $errors->first('keywords') }}}</small>
```

And you can use this also the show particular classes:

```
{{ $errors->has('keywords') ? 'has-error' : '' }}
```

Example:

```
 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('keywords') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
```

--

For creating a Helper file, and access them 'globally'

Create a folder named: `libraries`  ->  `app/libraries`

Create a file(class) in your library: `Helper.php`

Then add this code to `Helper.php`:

```
<?php

class Helper{

public function hasError($error)
{
   if(strlen($error) > 0) 
   {
       echo "has-error";
   }

}
```

Edit `composer.json` in your root of your application, and add: `"app/libraries"`

**Example (composer.json):**

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/libraries"
    ]
},
```

In your console type:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Now you can call your 'function' like this 'anywhere':

```
Helper::hasError($error);
```